# Use '<<' with rails model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a class **Letter** which contains its intended recipients. These recipients are either **Individuals** or **Groups**.

In order to populate both individuals and groups:

```
ind = Individual.new
template.individuals << ind

group = Group.new
template.groups << group
```

Is it possible to have a method named 'recipients' and use the shovel operator like this:

```
template.recipients << (either group or individual)
```

and then implement the method such that it places the recipient in the correct collection, i.e. if the recipient is a groups it should place it into self.groups and if the recipient is an individual it should place it in self.individuals!

Please note that my design prohibits me from inheriting these classes from a single base class and from having a single container to hold both classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Here is an example of using a proxy object to receive recipients using the shovel operator.

```
class Letter               # (or Template???)
  has_many :individuals
  has_many :groups

  class RecipientsProxy
    def initialize(letter)
      @letter = letter
    end

    def <<(recipient)
      case recipient
      when Individual then @letter.individuals << recipient
      when Group      then @letter.groups << recipient
      end
    end
  end

  def recipients
    @recipients_proxy ||= RecipientsProxy.new(self)
  end
end

letter = Letter.new
letter.recipients << Individual.new
letter.recipients << Group.new
letter.recipients << Individual.new
letter.recipients << Group.new
```

Perhaps there is a better approach to your problem, though. Maybe you could create a Recipient model which serves as a join between Letter and Individual/Group.

```
class Letter
  has_many :recipients
end

class Recipient
  belongs_to :letter

  belongs_to :individual
  belongs_to :group
end
```

### Follow Up

You could use method_missing to make the RecipientsProxy object forward method calls to a collection of all Individuals and Groups for the current Letter.

```
# RecipientsProxy
def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
  recipients = (@letter.individuals + @letter.groups)  # This will create an Array with all Individuals and Groups
  recipients.__send__(method_name, *args, &block)
end


letter.recipients.to_a
letter.recipients.each { |recipient| puts recipient.inspect }
```

Comment: that's pretty nifty. Ruby amazes me sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This in fact is what I was looking for... In regards to you comments, I could neither consider all individuals as groups nor decomposing groups into individuals. One last question: this mechanism assist us with populating the recipients. What if we wanted to get a hash of groups and individuals by calling letter.recipients? Is it possible to do so?

Comment: @WizardOfOgz: in class `Recipient` you have defined, should't it be `has_many groups`, if not Please explain how it will work.

Comment: @mdoust I'm not immediately seeing a way to return a Hash like you want by calling just `letter.recipients`. You may be able to use method_missing to get the functionality you need - see the Follow Up in my answer

Comment: @saurabh It is your choice whether to use has_many or belongs_to. You can make your app work either way. For me it makes more sense that each Recipient represents either one Individual or one Group.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any easy solution to achieve this with the `template.recipients << item` syntax, but you could add a method `add_recipient` that dispatch the given object to the right collection:

```
class Letter

  # ...

  def add_recipient(recipient)
    case recipient
      when Individual then self.individuals << recipient
      when Group      then self.groups << recipient
      # else raise "Invalid parameter: #{recipient}"
    end          
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, this approach will surely do what I want but I was considering if I could handle it with '<<'.